# Odoo 9 JavaScript Module Require Error

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-9

Odoo 9 now uses JavaScript module system inspired by requirejs. When I tried to import the `hr_attendance.hr_attendance module` defined in `hr_attendance/static/src/js/attendance.js`, I am getting a missing dependency error on the console. I have tried with the other JS modules such as `web.core` and `web.Model` and these are working. I have already defined `hr_attendance` in `__openerp__.py`.

```
odoo.define('my_timestamp.my_timestamp', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var attendance = require('hr_attendance.hr_attendance');
    console.log(attendance);

});
```

Comment: Try to add hr_attendance in depends.

Comment: AS I have mentioned above, I have already tried this. Restarted the server and upgraded the module but still no luck.

Comment: @macdelacruz, did you get answer?